# redux saga functin given Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

This is the code. The problem is with this line here:

```
const resp = (yield authService.login(payload))?.data;
```

I'm getting this error `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

I'm new to `redux-saga` so I don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
* worker(data: any): IterableIterator<any>  {
  try {
    yield put(loginRequesting());
    const payload = data.payload as ILogin;
    const resp = (yield authService.login(payload))?.data;
    // store token, update store and redirect to dashboard page
    yield authService.setAuthHeader(resp.token, USER_ROLE);

    const userResp = (yield userService.me()).data;
    yield put(updateCurrentUser(userResp));
    yield put(loginSuccess());

    Router.push('/');
  } catch (e) {
    const error = yield Promise.resolve(e);
    yield put(loginFail(error));
  }
}
```

I understand there's a solution for `property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'` but they did not mention `redux-saga` or how to solve this error.

Comment: Why not use the `call` effect like `yield call(authService.login, payload)?.data`? `redux-saga` documentation never tells us should call the API service directly.